# string comparison - does not produce the desired result

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a pandas `dataframe` where

```
print type(opp.columns[0])
print type('region')
```

results in:

```
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
```

and

```
print opp.columns[0]
```

produces `region`

I have verified no additional whitespaces are in the string with the strip function.
However:

```
print (opps.columns[0].strip() == 'region')
```

gives `False`

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: You're using `opps` and `opportunities` which may be different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) method to identify the actual string value that you are getting. There might be hidden characters like `"\n"` which are not otherwise visible

```
repr(opportunities.columns[0])
```